# 1px glitch appearing below image when browser re-sizes background image

Tags: html, css, image, browser, background-image

This is a bit of an odd one and may either be a browser glitch or something wrong with the image when saved out in Photoshop but I thought I’d ask anyway. When re-sizing a background image that is set to `background-size: cover;` an odd 1px line seems to appear at the base of the image. It become quite noticeable on the website as the background colour is black. It’s not one colour which makes me wonder if it is browser glitch, see below:

[image: See weird 1px glitch under image]

I have tried multiple images and I think it can be seen in Chrome and Safari. The glitch can definitely be replicated on [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8ya8vav/1/) in Chrome (you’ll need to rescale the browser window and it needs to be quite large to see it).

Comment: I can't seem to see this line, where should I be looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this an issue between `background-position: bottom` and `background-size: cover`. I have noticed that if we remove `background-position: bottom` there is no glitch. Probably an issue with Webkit browsers even though I haven't found a bug report for this.

You can solve this issue by using `background-position: 50% 99%` until the bug is fixed. If someone has a better answer I'll be interested to know :).

```css
body{
  background: #000;
}

.hero{
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/R7WAday.jpg');
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 99%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice job—should have spotted that! Looks like it must be a glitch in Webkit as you say.

Comment: Also realised that the 1px line was the image repeating underneath so adding `background-repeat: no-repeat;` also solves the issue.

Comment: That's true and it's a better solution! I tried it too but I must have spelt the property wrong because it wasn't working... Everything is easier with a fresh new eye :)!

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this problem, found little about it online, and found this post.

I found [this post](https://philfreo.com/blog/fixing-safaris-1px-background-image-centering-problem/) from 2009(!) where the author suggests using:

```
  .hero {
        background-position: 49.999% 0;
    }
```

or

```
  .hero {
        background-position: 50.001% 0;
    }
```

They had varied success for me in my situation. I ended up mostly using:

```
  .hero {
        background-position:bottom -1px left 0;
    }
```

As my designs allowed me to reduce the size by -1px, and this got rid of the issue.